# Parsing JSON in C# 4.0

Tags: json, c#-4.0

Can anyone help me to parse this JSON into an object IN C# 4.0.  I have spent the last two days trying.
I have JSON.NET and several other peoples suggestions to no avail.

I thought it would be best just to give the JSON sample and to ask for your suggestions.

```
{
"message-count":"1",
"messages":[
        {"to":"441234567890",
          "messageprice":"0.02900000",
          "status":"0",
          "messageid":"030000001DFE2CB1",
          "remainingbalance":"1.56500000",
                      "network":"23433"}
                ]
}
```

Many thanks,
Adrian

p.s Their is some nice code here, if you want to use github. https://github.com/lukesampson/HastyAPI.Nexmo

Comment: First of all, I'd recommend avoiding the dash in JSON keys: "message-count" will cause you extra work. Use "message_count"

Comment: Hi AD,
I have no control over this. This is what I get from the server. 
I have managed to sort it out.  I just had the class structure wrong when using JSON.Net.  It seems to take quite a while to load though.  
Why does Microsoft not have a reasonable introduction to JSON?

Comment: "message-count":"1" ?

Comment: @ADNow: why do you suggest to not use a dash in a property name? Is it because the C# language does not allow it (and thus require an extra attribute on the class)?

Comment: You cannot use dot syntax to reference the hyphenated keys in JavaScript, like data.message-count, you are forced to use data["message-count"]. I do not see Google suggesting to use dashes in their guidelines either: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jsoncstyleguide.xml#Property_Name_Guidelines

Answer (score 2):

I will cheat and create C# classes quickly using this tool: http://json2csharp.com/ (or just discovered http://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/)

[image]

Then I change C# classes to my liking

```
public class MessagesJSON
{
    public int MessageCount { get; set; }
    public List<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public string To { get; set; }
    public double MessagePrice { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string MessageId { get; set; }
    public double RemainingBalance { get; set; }
    public string Network { get; set; }
}
```

**MessagesJSON** is just a name I made that represents the JSON object that you are passing to C#.

I pass the JSON string from the client, e.g.

```
{\"MessageCount\":1,\"Messages\":[{\"To\":\"441234567890\",\"MessagePrice\":0.029,\"Status\":0,\"MessageId\":\"030000001DFE2CB1\",\"RemainingBalance\":1.565,\"Network\":\"23433\"}]
```

Then I can use JSON.NET to convert JSON to C# objects:

```
public void YourMethod(MessagesJSON json) {
   var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MessagesJSON>(json);
}
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Watch out for capitalisation.

If you want to use lower-case JSON keys only, change the C# classes to lower-case, e.g. **public double messageprice { get; set; }**

C# classes:

```
 public class MessagesJSON
    {
        public int message_count { get; set; }
        public List<Message> messages { get; set; }
    }

public class Message
{
    public string to { get; set; }
    public string messageprice { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string messageid { get; set; }
    public string remainingbalance { get; set; }
    public string network { get; set; }
}
```

This is as close to your JSON as you want:

```
{\"message_count\":1,\"messages\":[{\"to\":\"441234567890\",\"messageprice\":\"0.02900000\",\"status\":\"0\",\"messageid\":\"030000001DFE2CB1\",\"remainingbalance\":\"1.56500000\",\"network\":\"23433\"}]}
```

[image]

or use one of these solutions if you really like CamelCasing:

[CamelCase only if PropertyName not explicitly set in Json.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749046/camelcase-only-if-propertyname-not-explicitly-set-in-json-net)

[JObject & CamelCase conversion with JSON.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087340/jobject-camelcase-conversion-with-json-net)

I myself prefer attributes

```
public class Message
    {
        [JsonProperty("to")]
        public string To { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("messageprice")]
        public string MessagePrice { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("messageid")]
        public string MessageId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("remainingbalance")]
        public string RemainingBalance { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("network")]
        public string Network { get; set; }
    }
```

Pass your string:

```
"{\"message_count\":1,\"messages\":[{\"to\":\"441234567890\",\"messageprice\":\"0.02900000\",\"status\":\"0\",\"messageid\":\"030000001DFE2CB1\",\"remainingbalance\":\"1.56500000\",\"network\":\"23433\"}]}"
```

but get the pretty C# property names:

[image]

Comment: Hi Ad,
That's exactly what I did. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Create objects with the same structure as the json and call.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Entity>(json);
```

Edit. You have to use JSON.NET if u wanna do it this way.

Comment: Thanks Tan.  That's what I did do.